# ASP.Net 3.5/4.0 CodeBehind or CodeFile?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, code-behind

I read through the previous post: [CodeFile vs CodeBehind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73022/codefile-vs-codebehind), but I'm still confused on which I should use.  It sounds like CodeFile is the newer option that should be used, yet VS2010 generates CodeBehind when creating a new Web Form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your template, check out web site vs. web application.  I tend to prefer web application for several reasons, but that is  up to you.  If you see code-behind, you probably have selected that template.

Comment: Okay, that's what I did. Just wanted to verify that was the reason.  Does the code-behind require pre-compilation, or will new code get compiled on the fly?

Comment: Websites can be precompiled (or 'published'), otherwise pages get compiled on the fly. I also prefer web application projects however and would recommend them for any reasonable sized project.

Comment: Code-behind itself doesn't precompile but the code-behind is compiled into a single DLL, but web sites are dynamically compiled at runtime as mentioned by @richeym.  Precompilation can be done for both project types, as it also compiles the markup too, so there isn't the initial page compilation hit.