# ASP.NET C# and creating pages from master - "inherits" value is always wrong?

Tags: asp.net

I'm relatively new to ASP.NET (haven't touched it since .NET was first introduced). I'm using Visual Studio Express For Web 2012.

I've created a master page to work with. However, whenever I create a new page, the default value for "inherits" at the top of the page causes the page to not load, with a "could not load type" error.

I haven't even started coding yet, so I'm not sure what it's looking for.

Edit to add:

Top of a new page looks like this:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="login.aspx.cs" Inherits="Bitfork.login" %>
```

The generated code behind page:

```
namespace Bitfork
{
    public partial class login : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the markup

Comment: Can you post the exact error you're getting as well?

Comment: Your code looks good for me. Are you compiling the site before trying to access that page?

Comment: Have you tried switching to `CodeFile` instead of `CodeBehind`? `CodeBehind` requires the page to be compiled beforehand.

Comment: it was indeed that I needed to compile - I'm so used to just saving and then refreshing the page in my browser! Is there a reason to use CodeBehind instead of CodeFile?

Comment: @shifuimam well using `CodeBehind` means your web app is pre-compiled before deployment so it's better performance wise, however, restricts you from making changes on-the-fly.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was caused in my website when I was using `CodeBehind` property in `<%@ Page ..>` directive,

As soon as I changed it to :`CodeFile` , it worked without the need to recompile every time. I guess from ASP.NET 2.0 onwards this is the case for website templates.

What I observed was that [ framework 4 ], when I create website, the `<%@ Page ..>` directive contains `CodeFile`. When create WebApplication, then the `<%@ Page ..>`  directive contains: `CodeBehind`.

This post may be helpful: [ASP.Net 3.5/4.0 CodeBehind or CodeFile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585463/asp-net-3-5-4-0-codebehind-or-codefile)

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved - I didn't realize I needed to recompile the page between each page load.