# Converting CodeFile to CodeBehind

Tags: c#, .net, code-behind, page-directives

So I seem to have some difficulties with making my CodeFile reference into CodeBehind. Before you ask, I do not have Visual Studio and I'm not on Windows. The code is being hosted on an IIS server that I have access to.

```
<% @Page Language="C#" Inherits="corn.cheese.pies.CasLogin" CodeFile="anon.cs" %>
```

This code works perfectly, however upon changing it to:

```
<% @Page Language="C#" Inherits="corn.cheese.pies.CasLogin" CodeBehind="anon.cs" %>
```

The page returns an error:

```
Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'corn.cheese.pies.CasLogin'.
```

Comment: I believe code-behind requires the inherited control class to be available in the web app DLL. Why do you need / expect to be able to do this without Visual Studio?

Comment: Not an answer, really, but: why are you going from CodeFile -> CodeBehind? Generally people go the *other* way, since CodeFile is "newer" (in the relative "7 years old vs. 9 years old" sense.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Are you sure you understand the difference between CodeFile and CodeBehind? See, for example,  [CodeFile vs CodeBehind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73022/codefile-vs-codebehind) (ignore the accept answer, though, both links are dea) or [this article](http://www.ashchuan.com/blog/2011/03/31/codefile-and-codebehind-in-net-what-the-heck-is-the-difference/) about the difference.

In a nutshell:

A `CodeBehind` file is assumed to be compiled into an assembly that is deployed in the `bin` folder of your web site. When the ASP.NET engine loads your `aspx` file, it uses the `Inherits` directive to try to find that class. The `CodeBehind` file is primarily used to aid compiling (and tooling, e.g. "View Source") but the work is done at compile time.

A `CodeFile` file is located and compiled by ASP.NET at runtime, on demand. You can "pre-compile" your web site to fall back on the older model, which is useful if you won't want to deploy your source code to every web site. But by default, your `CodeFile` file is a `.cs` file that is deployed to the site, and the class is generated in the ASP.NET temporary storage folder. (From a technical perspective: `CodeFile` pages are `partial class` definitions, with only the custom code-behind part of the class actually deployed in the C# file; this is why `CodeFile` didn't exist initially, because the C# compiler could not initially do partial classes.)

By changing from `CodeFile` to `CodeBehind` you are telling ASP.NET to ignore the presence of the C# file, and only look for it in the compiled assembly. ASP.NET is, in turn, telling you that the compiled assembly doesn't actually contain the class you told it to look for.