# Adding method causes Compilation Error C# ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, compiler-errors

I am  trying to create a `webpage`, but when i create a `button` and add a `method` to it a `compilation error occurs`, when i remove the `method` from the button it work fine
i tried these steps

1. tried delete page, and redo it from from beginning
2. find the error `CS1061` online

3.adding method to button with different methods
 i am exhausted try to find what is the error pls help me!

```
  Server Error in '/' Application.

    Compilation Error
```

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

> Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.usermodification_aspx' does not
>   contain a definition for 'btnModify_Click' and no extension method
>   'btnModify_Click' accepting a first argument of type
>   'ASP.usermodification_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

```
    Source Error:


        Line 38:         SelectCommand="SELECT RoleName FROM aspnet_Roles"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        Line 39:     <br />
        Line 40:     <asp:Button ID="btnModify" runat="server" Text="Modify" 
        Line 41:         onclick="btnModify_Click" />
        Line 42:
```

---

```
namespace RentACar
 {
    public partial class UserModification : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btnModify_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GridViewRow row = gvUserRoles.SelectedRow;

            string username = row.Cells[0].Text;
             string role = row.Cells[1].Text;
             Roles.RemoveUserFromRole(username, role);
            string choosenrole = dllUserRoles.SelectedValue.ToString();
            Roles.AddUserToRole(username, choosenrole);

        }
    }
}`
```

---

```
      <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="UserModification.aspx.cs" Inherits="RentACar.UserModification" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
```

---

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnModify" runat="server" Text="Modify" 
        onclick="btnModify_Click" />
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Security;
```

Comment: @Rob solution should work, could you post aspx code for button ? from the error it looks fine.

Comment: please post the code from ASPX ? the top most line, Page tag and Button Tag

Comment: sry i misunderstanding its my first website :) i posted it

Comment: I have post answer, check it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `CodeFile` instead of `CodeBehind` in page tag. CodeBehind requires the solution to be compiled. There could be something wrong in your code. After using CodeFile attribute in the page tag, put a break point on your button event handler and see if you still get that error.

Comment: Thanks Thanks  Thanks!!!!!!! :) ,what is the difference between CodeBehind and CodeFile?

Comment: @xArd, check out this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73022/codefile-vs-codebehind

Answer (score 0):

Define the `btnModify_Click` method.

```
void btnModify_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    // do something.
}
```

Comment: The error occurs when i define the method :/ i check if its the same name and staff like that but still the same