# Finding what method is called

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have an ASPX page with no code behind (that is, no `.aspx.cs` with the same name).  In the code is this line:

```
<div style="overflow: hidden; text-align: center; z-index: 105;">
    <%= MainNavBarHTML %><%= SubNavBarHTML %>
</div>
```

I've searched the rest of the program for `MainNavBarHTML` and `SubNavBarHTMl`, but can't find any reference to them.  How do I find what fills those elements?

Comment: What does the page header look like?  Basically, what does the `CodeFile` directive reference?

Comment: Have you tried right-clicking on it and selecting "Go to definition" ? This should take you to the method - or the object browser if it's part of a library

Comment: Look at the codebehind file for a  `protected/public` variable with that name.

Comment: @TimSchmelter OP has stated that there isn't a code behind file available.

Comment: Is anything displayed?  Maybe the variables don't exist.

Comment: There is no codebehind file.  Something is being displayed in them.  They're in a .aspx file that is used as the header for another page and the header displays fine.  I just don't know what controls what is seen in the header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this as an answer now (rather than in the comments).

Your project will have the code somewhere, though it may be part of another library (DLL).

If you right-click on the property (in this case either `MainNavBarHTML` or `SubNavBarHTML`, and from the context-menu select "Go to definition" VS will show you either the code (if it's in a *.cs page) or load the object browser and navigate to that property, allowing you to see exactly where the property is located.

Depending on your VS settings <kbd>F12</kbd> may do nothing - does nothing on mine for example. Right-clicking and choosing "Go to definition" is the most stable way to navigate - in my opinion.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to check out the [CodeFile vs CodeBehind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73022/codefile-vs-codebehind) question.

If your ASPX markup has the `CodeFile` directive, it will look for the associated `.cs` file:

```
<%@ Page
    Language="C#"
    CodeFile="CustomerDetail.aspx.cs"
    Inherits="SomePage" %>
```

If, instead, it has the `CodeBehind` directive listed it will look in the `Bin` folder for an assembly that has the class defined:

```
<%@ Page
    Language="C#"
    CodeBehind="CustomerDetail.aspx.cs"
    Inherits="SomePage" %>
```

The naming of these two directives is beyond unfortunate. If the application is using `CodeBehind` (which it sounds like it is) you may not have access to the source and will be unable to view the definition for those properties, short of using a .NET reflection tool against the compiled assemblies.

Comment: @boilers222 Please post the page directive section in its entirety then.

Comment: @boilers222 The page directive is only the section I've listed above. If even that's too much to share then unfortunately I can't offer much more assistance.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio, Put your cursor on the text and press <kbd>F12</kbd> to jump to definition or right-click on the text and choose "Go to definition".

Comment: If the source isn't available, you won't be able to navigate to the definition.

Comment: @Yuck. If the source isn't available it should at least open the object browser so you can locate the library it's in.

Answer (score -2):

Boiler, the code is still there, you just have to select the file and hit <kbd>F7</kbd> and you will see the code...

Comment: what he is suggesting effectively takes the user to the code behind for that page. The OP doesn't have one. He needs to right-click on the code and "Go to definition". either that or i have mistaken the F7 shortcut for something other than 'View Code'