# Have to copy global.asax.cs to live server

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, global-asax

I have a web application which I have built and deployed to a web server.  We only deploy the aspx, plus dlls etc and not the source code.

When I try and access the web site I get the message "the file /global.asax.cs'does not exist".

If I copy it across to the server it works and the rest of the site is fine. No other C# source code is present on the site so it is obviously using the compiled DLL for everything but global.asax.cs

The global.asax file looks like this:

```
<%@ Application CodeFile="Global.asax.cs" Language="C#" Inherits="GTFC.Global" %>
```

and the global.asax.cs like this:

```
namespace GTFC
{
    public partial class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can fix it by changing `CodeFile` to `Codebehind`:

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Language="C#" Inherits="GTFC.Global" %>
```

Reading: [CodeFile vs CodeBehind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73022/codefile-vs-codebehind)