# face with this error when runnig my webapp on iis Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'Last_edition.Default'

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2015

I have a `webform` asp.net project (with framework 4.5.1) and I'm trying to put it an a virtual directory in `iis` (10) but i faced below error.

for details i should say, at first i went to `iis` i added a website with Last_Edition name and then set physical path where my project located.(the last edition subfolder in the visual studio solution).

```
http Hostname: desktop-62c6tdv (MY machine name) and port:80
```

so what could be the problem?

I checked:

1. Clean and rebuild everything
2. i tried using the automatic local iis connection that visual studio made for project and that works correctly(it means i can browse the webpages with http://localhost:1317/Default.aspx address that visual studio made for debug but i can't make same manualy)

   Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

   Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'Last_edition.Default'.

   Source Error:

   > Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Last_edition.Default" %>
   >   Line 2:
   >   Line 3:
   >
   > Source File: /default.aspx    Line: 1

Comment: when deploying the web application did you copy the dll as well?

Comment: @derloopkat actually i didn't know to what should i copy or don't copy so i set the whole project directory as physical path. and the .dll files are located in bin folder

Comment: I'd suggest to check you application pool is using that framework.

Comment: @derloopkat how can i check application pool? and what thing i can check in app pool?

Comment: In iis right click on your website, click on "advanced settings" (in the column at your right), get the Application pool name for your web site. Press cancel and go to Application Pools. Select the same application pool and go to advanced settings. Check .Net CLR Version (that's the framework) and if your application was compiled in 32 bits then Enable 32 bits should be True.

Comment: @derloopkat it's v4.0 but in web.config it set: targetFramework="4.5"
the app is compiled 64bits and it's false

Comment: Are your dlls into bin folder or bin/Debug, bin/Release, etc ?

Comment: @derloopkat it's in bin. 14 .dll files

Comment: In your aspx, replace CodeBehind with CodeFile.

Comment: it solved :D. Thank you very much!!! @derloopkat

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'sometype'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15071220/parser-error-message-could-not-load-type-sometype)