# Parser Error : error occurred during the parsing

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I have this web aplication, it works perfectly on my local machine, but when I publish didn't work, show me this error:

> Parser Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'Yes.Web.UI.admin.index'.

I already tried to search some answers here and a lot of sites but nothing helps me.
The error is in this line:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="index.aspx.cs" Inherits="Yes.Web.UI.admin.index" %>
```

and my `CodeBehind` is this one:

```
namespace Yes.Web.UI.admin
{
     public partial class index : AdministrativeBase
     {
     }
}
```

I ALREADY change `CodeBehind` to `CodeFile` but still doesn't work, I cleaned the `bin` folder and rebuild but also nothing.

Comment: Did your compiled DLL get copied to the server?

Comment: Yes @GabrielLuci I did this.

Comment: Seems like you might have the same issue as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15071220/parser-error-message-could-not-load-type-sometype) (use `CodeFile` instead of `CodeBehind`)

Comment: @GabrielLuci I've try this but still nothing