# Namespace reference problems

Tags: asp.net

I just felt a bit lazy this morning and thought of reusing the code that i already had created. What i did was, created a new website and added all the preexisting files to my website.

There were two namespaces. Mostly if i am not wrong it is the Dll(Namespace are not detected) problem.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Facebook; 
using Masterbinoy.DAL;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Masterbinoy.BAL.FbBal;
using Masterbinoy.DAL.UsersDAL;
using System.Configuration;
using DigiFolio.DAL.LogsDAL;
```

[image]

Now it gives me the following error when i build the project:
[image]
[image]

Comment: have you added the reference of both assemblies?

Comment: these are actually class files files with custom namespaces. Its included in the project but i do not know how to reference them without creating DLLs

Comment: then you dont need to import ...just create object of namespace then u can use that . masterbinoy.Dal.userdbaccess u = new masterbinoy.Dal.userdbaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys thanks for the help.

But i found a solution or a tweak:

1. I removed all the namespaces from the main project.
2. One thing i noticed was Main project from which i was copying was a **Web application** and the second one was a **web site**. I had to add all the class files to the **App_Code**(its the ASP folder type) Folder.

[image]
3. When i added the web application Master page to the website One thing worth noticing was, web application was using **CodeBehind** and in website i had to change the same property to CodeFile

> ```
> <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Index.master.cs" Inherits="Index" %>
> ```

I did not know the difference first but then i found [**it here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73022/codefile-vs-codebehind)

Now i am able to work fine. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs due to wrong build action being set in the imported class files.
Kindly check the Build Action property of the files. I hope it would be "Content". Make it "Compile".

Comment: In web application it was by default in compile mode. Thanks for you help though.