# Master page won't compile when referencing its own properties and members

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, master-pages, vs-web-application-project

When upgrading a dotnet **Web Site** based on asp.net WebForms to a **Web App** I'm having trouble with Master pages.

My Master pages contain, in their .aspx file markup, references like this:

```
<div>
   Name: <% =GetUserName() %>  Account: <% =AccountId %>
</div>
```

`GetUserName()` is a protected method defined in my master page's codebehind file, and `AccountId` is a protected field in the same place.

After doing the Web App upgrade (which involves automatically generating a `Site.Master.designer.cs` codebehind file to accompany my own `Site.Master.cs` codebehind file) compilation of the Master page (not the codebehind) starts to fail, rejecting the protected member references in the `<% =GetUserName() %>` constructs. VS 2015 Intellisense says `GetUserName not defined in this context.`

But the *Go To Definition...* item on VS2015's context menu still works for the offending protected member references. Weird.

When I make a new Web App project from scratch, it doesn't have this problem.  How can I fix this?  Or is there something special about upgraded Web Site projects that prevents these protected member references?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out.

The order of items matters in the `project.csproj`, and the conversion from Web Site to Web App doesn't always get it right.

To fix, close up VS2015, then use a text editor to open your `project.csproj` file. (It will be named for your project.) Look for the `<Compile...>` tags for your Master page's codebehind files.

Then make sure the tag to compile your own codebehind file comes **before** the one for the `.designer.cs` code, like this:

```
<Compile Include="Site.Master.cs">
  <DependentUpon>Site.Master</DependentUpon>
  <SubType>ASPXCodeBehind</SubType>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="Site.Master.designer.cs">
  <DependentUpon>Site.Master</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

In my experience, these tags were widely separated in the automatically generated `.csproj` file.

At any rate, moving one of them so they were in order resolved my problem.

Don't forget to Clean and Rebuild your project in VS2015 if you change your `.csproj` files outside the IDE.