# Difference between "codebehind" and "source"

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can any one tell me with example what's the difference between **Codebehind="MyCode.aspx.cs"** and **Src="MyCode.aspx.cs"**?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73022/codefile-vs-codebehind)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**CodeBehind**

> Specifies the name of the compiled file that contains the class
>   associated with the page. This attribute is not used at run time. This
>   attribute is used for Web application projects. The CodeFile attribute
>   is used for Web site projects.
>
> Needs to be compiled ( asp.net 1.1 model) and compiled binary is
>   placed in the bin folder of the website. You need to do a compile in
>   visual studio before you deploy. Good model when you do not want the
>   source code to be viewable as plain text ... for example when
>   delivering to a customer who you not have obligation to provide code.

**Src**

> Specifies a path to a source file containing code that is linked to
>   the page. In the linked source file, you can choose to include
>   programming logic for your page either in a class or in code
>   declaration blocks.
>
> You can use the Src attribute to link build providers to the page. For
>   more information, see the [BuildProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.web.compilation.buildprovider%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class. Also, in versions of
>   ASP.NET prior to 2.0, the Src attribute was used as an alternative way
>   to link a code-behind file to a page. In ASP.NET 2.0, the preferred
>   approach to linking a code-behind source file to a page is to use the
>   Inherits attribute to specify a class, along with the CodeFile
>   attribute to specify the path to the source file for the class.
>
> You provide the source file with the solution for deployment. ASP.NET
>   2.0 runtime compiles the code when needed. The compiled files are at Microsoft.NET[.NET version]\Temporary ASP.NET Files.

Its always recommended to check the official documentations first. See the [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ydy4x04a%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for this Question.

Comment: In short terms, CodeBehind gets built into an assembly, whereas the file referenced in the CodeFile/src needs to be deployed with the ASPX on the web server. With CodeBehind approach you'll need to deploy a new assembly for each change to the backend logic, whereas the CodeFile approach you can edit backend code from the server (directly in the .cs file)

Answer (score 1):

codebehind is a particular particular technique born with NET.
This allows you to write application code by separating it from the graphical presentation.

For example:

```
<script runat="server" src="MyCods.cs" />
```

execute a primitive code-behind. this because the code isnot compiled and not generate. For This reason remain a simple format plain text.

Il codebehind is default applied  in the major IDE as: 
Microsoft Visual Studio 2003 - .net 1
Microsoft Web Matrix - .net 1
Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 .net 2
Microsoft Web Developer Express .net 2

This implies that the association of the source code, in the form of DLLs, the page to which it is related. I remind you that each page is viewed. NET as a single class, which will inherit the code derived from. Previously compiled dll.