# Receiving MS Visual Studio build error: The name 'Model' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, sql

I am completely new to ASP/C#/VisualStudio. I took a course and am trying to build my first project. I feel like if I could get past this hurdle I'm destined for greatness!

I am simply trying to create a page that will insert data into a database.

Below is the contents of my AddNewOrder.aspx file:

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="AddNewOrder.aspx.cs" Inherits="MemberPages_AddNewOrder" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Order Database > Add New Order</title>
    <link href="../StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1 {
            height: 44px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page">
        <!--#include file="../Includes/sidebar.inc"-->
        <div id="content">
            <h1>Add New Order</h1>
              <form id="form1" runat="server">
                  <table class="contenttablecontainer">
                      <tr>
                          <td>
                   <table class="newordertable">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Item Model:</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="Model" runat="server" Columns="40" Rows="6" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Vendor:</td>
                        <td><asp:DropDownList ID="Vendor" runat="server" DataSourceID="VendorDataSource" DataTextField="VendorName" DataValueField="VendorName">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="VendorDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Vendors_Connection %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [VendorName] FROM [vendors]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

And below is the code from my AddNewOrder.aspx.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
public partial class MemberPages_AddNewOrder : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
        ["Orders_ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    protected void AddOrderBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("AddNewOrderProc", conn);
        comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Model", Model.Text);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Vendor", Vendor.Text);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblError.Text = ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I am using Visual Studio Professional 2017.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `CodeFile` attribute in your `.aspx` page to `CodeBehind` then rebuild and that should fix it.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73022/codefile-vs-codebehind) for more details.

**EDIT**

Now either one is building for me... Maybe try clean then rebuild solution from the *Build* menu at the top.

**Styling/Syntax**

On another note you can simplify your control declarations if they're not going to act as containers for any other controls. e.g. since your `Models` text box doesn't have any other controls between it's tags you can simplify from:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Model" runat="server" Columns="40" Rows="6" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
```

to:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Model" runat="server" Columns="40" Rows="6" TextMode="MultiLine" />
```

The same applies for your `DropDownList` and `SqlDataSource` controls.

Also it is common practise to prefix a controls `ID` with shorthand for the control type. So `Model` would become `tbModel` and `Vendor` would be `ddlVendor`, a label is `lbl`, a listbox `lb` etc; it helps by providing context around the type of control you are interacting with when you're working in the `.cs` file, yeah you can hover over the variable and it will tell you it's type but that's extra effort. ;-)

Comment: Thank you! I greatly appreciate your feedback! Unfortunately, using CodeBehind didn't resolve the issue. Now that I know about it though, I want to use it. Your other suggestions were greatly appreciated! Thanks again!

Comment: @AndyID18 did you get it resolved in the end - if so you should post how you resolved it. 