# Difference between "~/Site.Master" and "./Site.Master"

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, master-pages

Attempting my first "HELLO WORLD" type web app which I based on a sample program that showed godaddy setup.

Using visual studio 2017 and C#.  My program builds and runs just fine at `localhost/xxxxx` but fails when I attempt to publish it. Error says

> Parser Error Message: The file '/Site.Master' does not exist

Googling I read a suggestion to use "`./`" instead of what VS2017 created":

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="BoincStats._Default" %>
```

So I changed that tilde to a dot and not only do I get a new error

> BoincStats.SiteMaster not found

but I also discover that it does no longer runs on my Windows-10-x64 system unless I put the "`~/`" back in.

The same googling suggested replacing `CodeBehind` with `CodeFile` which failed to even publish.

For a starter, I would like to know difference between those functions and when to use them.

In Ubuntu, I have executed `mkdir "~/vnc"` and it makes a hidden directory in my root named *vnc*.  Looking at the remote website (godaddy) and my local drive, I do not see any directory *"Site.Master"* only a file at "JTest" where it got installed.
[image: VS and FileZilla]

Comment: You should also tag this question with either `asp.net` or `asp.net-core`, depending on which one you're using. I assume Core since you mention Ubuntu, and the meaning of `~` to an operation system is very different from how ASP.NET (any version) interprets it.

Comment: In ASP.NET, the tilde is shorthand for the site root. That way you don't have to change anything when debugging on `https://localhost` or deploying to `https://foo.com`.

Comment: `.` is web url route but if you have a sub directory is will not consider this aka same same, but if your site is www.goo.com/sysadmin/ in other words you have different apps for www.goo.com/ and www.goo.com/sysadmin/ then i believe if you were deployed in sysadmin and you used `.` it would nav you to www.goo.com/ in stead of www.goo.com/sysadmin/ i think it become applicable for sub directory hosting mostly. I could be wrong but this is what my understanding is.

Answer (score 1):

1. `~/` refers to the application root directory, whereas `./` refers to the file's directory. This notation is also implemented in methods such as `@Url.Content()` and `Server.MapPath()`.
2. As for `CodeFile` vs. `CodeBehind`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/954873/21336).

Comment: Just a note: you tagged this question `asp.net-core` but MasterPages are exclusive to ASP.NET WebForms (.NET Framework upto 4.x) and do not exist in .NET Core; for that reason I re-tagged it.