# A server side object cannot be recognized in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

> Aspx

```
<a href="signUp.aspx" class="nav-link w-nav-link"><%=Account%></a>
```

> aspx opening

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="contact.aspx.cs" Inherits="RapidTyper.contact" %>
```

> code behind

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

    namespace RapidTyper
    {
        public partial class contact : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            public string Account = "Sign In";
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (Session["user"] != null)
                {
                    Account = "Account";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**The problem:
the Account in the aspx is not recognized and returns the error : "The name 'Account' does not exist in the current context"**

Comment: Please share the first three lines of the aspx.

Comment: Have you recompiled the app?

Comment: this.Account also doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error goes away when you compile and run your project. But in case you want not to have it without compiling then the fix is to change your `CodeBehind` attribute to `CodeFile` attribute *(not recommended)* in the `Page` directive in your `ASPX` page *(the first line in aspx)*. Here is an [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/954873/4308286) explaining the difference between these attributes.

[image]

***Update*** 
 Since, referencing the properties from `CodeBehind` in `aspx` page looks easier with `<%%>` syntax but it has its limitations, such as, you cannot retrieve the values until the page is fully posted back to the server, if you use it inside an `UpdatePanel` it might throw some exceptions.

It is always better to set such values from CodeBehind like, if you make your `anchor` element run at server and then set it's `InnerText` property On `Page_Load` event, then it will be an efficient approach. i.e:

```
<a href="signUp.aspx" class="nav-link w-nav-link" runat="server" id="aSignup"></a>
```

Now in your code behind on `Page_Load` event do:

```
public string Account = "Sign In";
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostback)
    {
        aSignup.InnerText = Account;
    }

}
```

Comment: I have tried the updated answer but it is returning an error in the code behind: The name 'aSignup' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: You should give it the id, see my `aspx` markup. I have an attribute in the anchor element as `id="aSignup" runat="server"`

Comment: yeah, I konw, I did it and it still doensn't work.
<a href="signUp.aspx" class="nav-link w-nav-link" runat="server" id="aSignup"></a>

Comment: That maybe because you would still be using `CodeFile`, If you are changing the way you do that, you should change that to `CodeBehind` attribute so the `designer.cs` file can be rebuilt.

Comment: No, I have tried it in another page which is still has the CodeBehind attribute:
`<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="learn.aspx.cs" Inherits="RapidTyper.learn" %>`

  `<a href="signUp.aspx" class="nav-link w-nav-link" runat="server" 
     id="aSignup"></a>`

Comment: Please post a new question with the full aspx page code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64201611/aspx-element-with-runat-server-is-not-recognized-in-the-server-by-id