# aspx element with runat="server" is not recognized in the server by id

Tags: c#, asp.net

**The problem:
aSignup is not recognized and returns the error :
"The name 'aSignup' does not exist in the current context**

> aspx

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="learn.aspx.cs" 
    Inherits="RapidTyper.learn" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
      <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Learn</title>
    <meta content="Learn" property="og:title">
      <meta content="Learn" property="twitter:title">
      <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">


    </head>
    <body>
      <div data-collapse="medium" data-animation="default" data-duration="400" role="banner" class="navbar w-nav">
        <div class="w-container"><a href="Home.aspx" class="brand w-clearfix w-nav-brand"><img src="images/keyboard.png" width="52" alt="" class="stone-logo"><div class="logo-text">Rapid typer</div></a>
          <nav role="navigation" class="nav-menu w-nav-menu">a href="signUp.aspx" class="nav-link w-nav-link" runat="server" id="aSignup"></a></nav>
          <div class="menu-button w-nav-button">
<form runat="server">
    </form>

      <script src="https://d3e54v103j8qbb.cloudfront.net/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.dc5e7f18c8.js?site=5f47de6d60aae827039f6108" type="text/javascript" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="js/webflow.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <!-- [if lte IE 9]><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/placeholders/3.0.2/placeholders.min.js"></script><![endif] -->
    </body>
    </html>
```

> code behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace RapidTyper
{
    public partial class learn : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                aSignup.InnerText = "Account";
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**The problem:
aSignup is not recognized and returns the error :
"The name 'aSignup' does not exist in the current context**

Comment: Please share the full `aspx` page code.

Comment: I have create the same example and its works as expected - so there is an error somewhere else - see and compile the full project to locate any other error

Comment: The whole HTML seems messed up. It is obvious that the compiler would be confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the fact that you have missed the `<` before declaring the anchor element as *@Joel Coehoorn* suggested, I would like to bring another thing in notice that is, while you are working with asp.net `WebForms`, make sure there is at least and at most ONE html `form` element with a `runat="server"` attribute on it as the parent element of all the server controls, which is not present in your markup. This could be a second issue on your page.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server"> <!-- This should be the parent of all the server controls. -->
    <div data-collapse="medium" data-animation="default" data-duration="400" role="banner" class="navbar w-nav">
        <div class="w-container">
            <a href="Home.aspx" class="brand w-clearfix w-nav-brand">
                <img src="images/keyboard.png" width="52" alt="" class="stone-logo" />
                <div class="logo-text">Rapid typer</div>
            </a>
            <nav role="navigation" class="nav-menu w-nav-menu">
                <a href="signUp.aspx" class="nav-link w-nav-link" runat="server" id="aSignup"></a>
            </nav>
            <div class="menu-button w-nav-button">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- YOUR Scripts Go here-->
</form>
```

---

**UPDATE**

I see, you have updated you question and you have added a `<form runat="server"></form>` tag as well, but it is not added correctly as I suggested. So, what I am going to do is, modify your whole code as I see it suitable and you should then copy the entire `aspx` page.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="learn.aspx.cs"
    Inherits="RapidTyper.learn" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Learn</title>
    <meta content="Learn" property="og:title">
    <meta content="Learn" property="twitter:title">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div data-collapse="medium" data-animation="default" data-duration="400" role="banner" class="navbar w-nav">
            <div class="w-container">
                <a href="Home.aspx" class="brand w-clearfix w-nav-brand">
                    <img src="images/keyboard.png" width="52" alt="" class="stone-logo" />
                    <div class="logo-text">Rapid typer</div>
                </a>
                <nav role="navigation" class="nav-menu w-nav-menu">
                    <a href="signUp.aspx" class="nav-link w-nav-link" runat="server" id="aSignup"></a>
                </nav>
                <div class="menu-button w-nav-button">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- YOUR Scripts Go here-->
        <script src="https://d3e54v103j8qbb.cloudfront.net/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.dc5e7f18c8.js?site=5f47de6d60aae827039f6108" type="text/javascript" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="js/webflow.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!-- [if lte IE 9]><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/placeholders/3.0.2/placeholders.min.js"></script><![endif] -->
    </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Please replace your `aspx` code with the above.

Comment: I have added an empy form with runat="server" attribute but it still not working.

Comment: Change your anchor element with this line of markup: `<a href="signUp.aspx" class="nav-link w-nav-link" runat="server" id="aSignup"></a>`

Comment: Sorry but , what is anchor element ...?

Comment: the element `<a` is called the anchor element.

Answer (score 2):

This might be just a typo in the question, but the element is missing the opening angle bracket (`<`).

Even then, rather than `<a` you should look at an `<asp:HyperLink`.

Answer (score -1):

<strike>is the '**a**' tag inside of an '**asp:Content**' tag? All elements referenced in the code behind should be inside of **asp:** tags</strike> EDIT: - only when using **MasterPageFile** directive.

Does the designer **learn.aspx.designer.cs** have a declaration for `aSignup` ?
e.g.:

```
namespace RapidTyper
{
    public partial class learn
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// aSignup control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Auto-generated field.
        /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
        /// </remarks>
        protected global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlAnchor aSignup;
    }
}
```

Comment: -1 because it is not true that all elements referenced in the codebehind should be INSIDE of asp tags. In order to reference an element it is only necessary that element should have the attribute `runat="server"` and an id.

Comment: @JamshaidKamran if not using a MasterPageFile directive in the Page that's correct (didn't notice that from his question).
Edited answer to check the designer.